# Run time error in linked list

Tags: c++11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node{
int data;
Node* next;
};
void deletelist(Node*&head)
{
Node* temp=new Node;
temp=head;
while(head!=NULL)
{
head=head->next;
delete(temp);
temp=head;
}
}
int main() {
Node aman={1,NULL},manjot={2,&aman},sima={3,&manjot},jasbir={4,&sima};
Node* head=&jasbir;
deletelist(head);
return 0;
}
```

Why this is showing run time error (delete(temp); function is not working here but why)?

Comment: You're not properly allocating, but de-allocating.

Comment: you trying to de-allocate(i.e. delete) a variable, which is never allocated(i.e. new) at first place.

Comment: BTW you don't need a `deletelist`, because all the variables will be destructed once their scope ends.

Comment: plz explain how to properly allocate here

Comment: If you never called `new` why do you call `delete`?

Answer (score -1):

Working code for you. Take special note of two scopes in main.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node{
int data;
Node* next;
};
void print(Node*head)
{
while(head!=NULL)
{
    std::cout<<head->data<<'\n';
    head=head->next;
}
}
int main() {
    Node* head;
    {
        Node aman={1,NULL},manjot={2,&aman},sima={3,&manjot},jasbir={4,&sima};
        head=&jasbir;
        print(head);
    }
    {
        Node aman={10,NULL},manjot={20,&aman},sima={30,&manjot},jasbir={40,&sima};
        head=&jasbir;
        print(head);
    }
return 0;
}
```

[example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4c707f30bec1f5a)

Comment: you have written same thing two times and there is no delete function

Comment: yeah,. this is to suggest the meaning of scope. You do not need to delete something which never allocated using `new`. You are already writing scope-safe code, so don't worry about `delete`.